# Git log with NetBeans GUI

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-7, git-log

I am new to Git and I am wondering if I can view the history of commits so I can extract a kind of log from it. I found out you can do this with `git log` command but I do not have a standalone installation, I used it right from NetBeans (v7.2.1).

Is there a way to see that through the NetBeans GUI? If not, is there a way to still do that with command line? Maybe if I install git separately or something?

Comment: Definitely is not a netbeans+git question! You should change the title as well.

Comment: @Gilbertoca well I can actually remove this question alltogether, but I was trying to view the git log from within netbeans, how is that not related to netbeans?

Comment: You asked (about commit history)and answered it in the first paragraph: git log. After that you asked about how to use it: command line, separated gui ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely, installing the standalone version of Git is worthy to try. Then you can use any of these methods to see the log:

```
git log
git gui
```

You can even define an alias to show git logs in a more human friendly format as described in https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig:

```
git config --global alias.lg "log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit"
```

Then you can use `git lg` command to show a pretty git log of your current branch.

Comment: I confirm you can use the bash command with the repository netbeans is creating, and you can get a log.

Answer (score 3):

NetBeans 8.2, to view the log change as Git log  command line, you can right click on the project → Git → Show History. It will show you the log for the project.

Comment: Although I have git installed, I prefer this answer as you easily use this within NetBeans.